# Making Eclipse for C++ developers compile

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos, osx-snow-leopard

I've downloaded [Eclipse for C/C++ for Mac OSX](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers/heliossr1). I'm running Snow Leopard. Now, when trying to run the Hello World application on Eclipse, it is complaining that

[image]

What might be the issue? Maybe I don't have (or Eclipse can't find) where my C++ compiler is? If that is the issue, what should I install and how should I proceed so that Eclipse recognizes it?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like gcc is not in your path.  Try adding the path to gcc (should be in /usr/bin by default) to your PATH environment variable and relaunch Eclipse.

Comment: It seems that it isn't there. So I don't have it installed

Comment: You should install Xcode on your machine since it installs gcc as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try adding it to Eclipse's preferences. I believe you'll find an item in the eclipse preferences which will allow you to point eclipse at the location of gcc.  This would come in handier then benw's answer in my opinion because you're not changing anything with the system itself.  Developing often involves setting things up specific to your development environment.  Although it seems like gcc would be on your PATH already if it were installed.  Have you installed Apple's developer tools by any chance?

Thanks.

Since I cannot comment on that comment you just put above.  Install the Apple Developer tools.  You can go [here](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/) to download them.  I just used gcc on my work mac today, and I never installed gcc specifically so it had to have been installed when I installed the developer tools.